# When to copy database on android device?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, asynchronous

I'm developing an app, which uses its own sqlite database to display data. I have functions and code which manage the database: create it, copy the db to the device.
The question is: **when** to do all this?

Actually I create the database in the very moment I need it, but the first time I do it (app loaded on a "clean" device), my function starts to copy the db into the device and then fails the first execution of the code about the database, for, the first time, the copy needs a moment to complete, and the process is trying to access the database, but it's trying to do it BEFORE it is fully copied.
The next time I launch the app, all goes fine, because the database has already been copied.

So, which is the right moment to do the copy? And can I do it only the first time the app is opened?

Comment: It sounds like you are doing it at a reasonable time, but you need to prevent access until it is done.  Showing a progress dialog (or even a simple splash screen) over or in place of your normal UI could be the start of a way to do that.

Comment: it's not a bad idea, i think i'll do it as the app opens with a progress dialog, like you said. Thank you